# How do I figure out the equivalent resistance of a network of resistors on a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, resistance

I am trying to figure out what the equivalent resistance would be at a certain point in a resistor network given different conditions of the GPIO pins they are connected to.

Configuration 1 is when the OUT pin on the micro is driven HIGH: In this case I know R1 and R3 are in parallel to one another, but I'm blanking on whether or not R2 would be a factor to the overall resistance seen for a device plugging into P.O.I? also blanking on what the voltage would be as seen on the IN pin.

Configuration 2 is when the OUT pin on the micro is driven LOW, this case I have the same questions as above with the added question of can we consider R2 and R3 as parallel resistors? [image: Resistor network diagram]

Comment: If the load is high impedance then R3 has no effect. PO.1 sees 
1/(1/ R1)+(1/R2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Answer**

The equivalent impedance at P.O.I. is simply the two resistors in parallel \$R_1 \parallel R_3\$.

**Detailed Answer**

We make the following assumptions in this analysis:

- The node IN has "infinite" input impedance -- its impedance is high enough that near-zero current flows through \$R_2\$ and so \$R_2\$ has no influence on the equivalent impedance seen.
- The node OUT has "zero" output impedance -- when it is high we can treat OUT as a dead short to 3.3V, and when it is low we can treat OUT as a dead short to ground.

The equivalent impedance for the other resistors is found using [Thévenin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem), which basically says that we can model this point by a voltage \$V_{th}\$ and a resistance \$R_{th}\$. To find these values, we find the open-circuit voltage \$V_{oc}\$ at P.O.I. if it is left as an open circuit, and the short-circuit current \$I_{sc}\$ through P.O.I. if we tie it to ground. Then \$V_{th} = V_{oc}\$, and \$R_{th} = {V_{oc} \over I_{sc}}\$. So the analysis becomes pretty straightforward:

If OUT is high (3.3V):

$$V_{th} = V_{oc} = 3.3V$$
$$I_{sc}= {3.3V \over R_1 \parallel R_3}$$
$$R_{th} = {V_{oc} \over I_{sc}} = {3.3V \over {3.3V \over R_1 \parallel R_3}} = R_1 \parallel R_3$$

If OUT is low (0V):
$$V_{th} = V_{oc} = 3.3V \cdot {R_3 \over R_1 + R_3}$$
$$I_{sc}= {3.3V \over R_1}$$
$$R_{th} = {V_{oc} \over I_{sc}} = {3.3V \cdot {R_3 \over R_1 + R_3} \over {3.3V \over R_1}} = {R_1R_3 \over R_1 + R_3} = R_1 \parallel R_3$$

So in both cases the impedance at P.O.I. looks like \$R_1 \parallel R_3\$, but the impedance is connected to a different effective voltage at the other end, depending on the voltage at OUT.

Comment: Unless R1// R3 are = 5k or less then you have a 1% or more error in estimate since zout ~ 50 Ohms. THen if > 1% of either load impedance at POI or IN then you get a 1% or more error in voltage

Comment: So R2 is a resistor external to the micro, not the internal GPIO resistance. I don’t think that would change your response though. So my intention is to be able to change the equivalent pull-up resistance by toggling the OUT pin. However based on your answer it seems that this solution won’t work. Im basicallly trying to change the usb cc line advertisement through this method.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I haven't read many microcontroller data sheets lately, but from what I recall their outputs usually drive with less than 50 ohms impedance. But I'll edit to note that all the calcs above presume that Rout << R3 and Rin is very large. (Impedance at the other side of P.O.I. is a moot point, since we are simply characterizing the impedance seen at the other side of P.O.I.)

Comment: @Jawzie correct on both counts. It's understood that R2 is external to the micro, but the point is that if IN has a very high input impedance, then it may be considered an open circuit (no current flowing through R2) so R2 does not contribute to the overall impedance seen. Also correct that the Thevenin equivalent circuit tells us that you cannot change apparent impedance by switching the voltage at OUT. You'd need to add in a transistor or some other type of closed/open switch after R3 to accomplish that.

Comment: 3V3  max CMOS  is 25 Ohms, 5V5 max CMOS is 50 Ohms @Mr.Snrub +/-50%